# ajax ie cross browser activexobject questions

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I am a beginner in AJAX.  I had a question I couldn't find on the internet so I came here :).  My first question is has to do with the block of code below.

```
function createXHR() {
  var iexhr...;

  iexhr = ["MSXML2.XMLHttp.7.0", "MSXML2.XMLHttp.6.0", "MSXML2.XMLHttp.5.0", "MSXML2.XMLHttp.4.0", "MSXML2.XMLHttp.3.0", "MSXML2.XMLHttp", "MSXML3.XMLHttp", "Microsoft.XMLHttp"];
}
```

My question to the code above is:  Throughout my googling and research I collect code samples that use different versions xmlhttprequest.  I wanted to create a cross browser xhr, and was wondering if all of these versions were important to keep, or should I only be using one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you want any of those.

There's really two versions of XHRs that you need to worry about: `window.ActiveXObject( "Microsoft.XMLHTTP")` for oldIE and `window.XMLHttpRequest()` for everybody else.

The usual pattern you'll see is something like:

```
if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
    return new window.XMLHttpRequest();
} 
else {
    return new window.ActiveXObject( "Microsoft.XMLHTTP" );
}
```

Or something like that, depending on what you're trying to do.

However, there's a lot more to XHR than returning Objects, such as monitoring state and errors, so this is precisely why folks use libraries for this sort of thing. Don't reinvent the wheel.